# bug in scripts/Training.pl or HTKTools/HMGenS.c?

Tags: ubuntu, speech-synthesis, htk, hts

I am trying to build a voice file using Tensorflow, with the HTS demo
voice `HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT`. But it crashes with segfaults.
After checking for null on a few pointers in HHed.c and Model.c to
prevent segfaults, I ran Again and got segfaults in HMGenS.

On investigation , I found that the hmmDir and hmmExt are initialized
to NULL, but were being referenced anyway.

I tried to provide a value for hmmDir in scripts/Training.pl but it
still crashes because hmmExt is NULL.

What is the correct way to build a voice using Tensorflow to generate
a Voice File for HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT?

Part of the log generated by the command `make voice`:

```
===================================================================================
Start generating speech parameter sequences (dnn) at Fri Jan 19
01:20:37 UTC 2018
===================================================================================

/home/ubuntu/pax/bin/HMGenS -A -B -C
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/configs/ver1/syn.cnf
-D -T 1 -t 1500 100 5000 -S
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/data/scp/gen.lab.scp
-c 0 -d /home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/dnn/ver1/models
-H /home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/models/ver1/cmp/re_clustered_all.mmf.1mix
-N /home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/models/ver1/dur/re_clustered_all.mmf.1mix
-M /home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/gen/ver1/dnn/0
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/models/ver1/cmp/tiedlist
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/models/ver1/dur/tiedlist

HTK Configuration Parameters[25]
  Module/Tool     Parameter                  Value
#                 CDGV                        TRUE
#                 GVOFFMODEL      StrVec 3 pau h# brth
#                 OPTKIND                   NEWTON
#                 GVWEIGHT                       1
#                 HMMWEIGHT                      1
#                 STEPDEC                 0.500000
#                 STEPINC                 1.200000
#                 STEPINIT                       1
#                 MINEUCNORM              0.010000
#                 GVEPSILON               0.000100
#                 MAXGVITER                     50
#                 GVHMMLIST
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/gv/ver1/models/tiedlist
#                 GVMODELMMF
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/gv/ver1/models/clustered_all.mmf
#                 USEGV                       TRUE
#                 EMEPSILON               0.000100
#                 MAXEMITER                     20
#                 WINDIR
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/data/win
#                 WINFN           StrVec 3 mgc.win1 mgc.win2 mgc.win3
StrVec 3 lf0.win1 lf0.win2 lf0.win3
#                 PDFSTREXT       StrVec 2 mgc lf0
#                 PDFSTRORDER        IntVec 2 35 1
#                 PDFSTRSIZE          IntVec 2 1 3
# HGEN            TRACE                          1
#                 USEALIGN                    TRUE
#                 NATURALWRITEORDER              TRUE
#                 NATURALREADORDER              TRUE

GV enabled
 42429 Logical/42429 Physical Models Loaded, VecSize=36
HMGenS: HMM definition directory used :
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/dnn/ver1/models
Initialize: hmmDir =
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/dnn/ver1/models
 hmmExt = (null)
LoadHMMSet : Trying to open file
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/dnn/ver1/models/d^ae-n+d=ah@2_2/A:1_1_3/B:1-0-3@1-1&4-5#3-3$3-3!1-1;1-3|ae/C:1+0+2/D:content_1/E:cc+1@4+4&3+1#1+3/F:in_1/G:9_8/H:8=7^4=5|L-L%/I:6=3/J:56+45-8
  ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/dnn/ver1/models/d^ae-n+d=ah@2_2/A:1_1_3/B:1-0-3@1-1&4-5#3-3$3-3!1-1;1-3|ae/C:1+0+2/D:content_1/E:cc+1@4+4&3+1#1+3/F:in_1/G:9_8/H:8=7^4=5|L-L%/I:6=3/J:56+45-8
  ERROR [+7010]  LoadHMMSet: Can't find file
  ERROR [+9928]  Initialise: LoadHMMSet failed
 FATAL ERROR - Terminating program /home/ubuntu/pax/bin/HMGenS
Error in /home/ubuntu/pax/bin/HMGenS    -A -B -C
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/configs/ver1/syn.cnf
-D -T 1                                                      -t 1500
100 5000  -S /home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/data/scp/gen.lab.scp
-c 0 -d /home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/dnn/ver1/models
-H /home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/models/ver1/cmp/re_clustered_all.mmf.1mix
-N /home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/models/ver1/dur/re_clustered_all.mmf.1mix
-M /home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/gen/ver1/dnn/0
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/models/ver1/cmp/tiedlist
/home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/models/ver1/dur/tiedlist
```

Comment: I have created a tag for [tag:hts] hoping this will draw more attention on library-specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
LoadHMMSet : Trying to open file /home/ubuntu/work/vq/repos/demos/dnn/SLT/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT/dnn/ver1/models/d^ae-n+d=ah@2_2/A:1_1_3/B:1-0-3@1-1&4-5#3-3$3-3!1-1;1-3|ae/C:1+0+2/D:content_1/E:cc+1@4+4&3+1#1+3/F:in_1/G:9_8/H:8=7^4=5|L-L%/I:6=3/J:56+45-8
```

suggests that the configuration file you created is wrong. It used question file instead of scp file which should just list the filenames. You need to review the configuration and try to figure out how question file placed there. Most likely you just confused the files on preparation.

You've also asked this question on [mailing list](http://hts.sp.nitech.ac.jp/hts-users/spool/2018/msg00004.html).

Comment: Thank you Nikolay,  But without specifying the -d it used to crash too. Have you been able to build a voice file using tensor flow?   Did you have to make any changes to make that happen?

Comment: I wrote nothing about `-d`, you problem is different. 

You usually make small changes in every task like this since complex setups never work out that smoothly. You just need to understand what is going on to pass through it.